# SSH and Git Clone

Tags: git, ssh, git-branch

Is it possible to ssh to a remote server and trigger a git clone. ie I need to ssh to server A, create a folder /tmp/A and clone a repository with all its contents on A. The ssh keys of the remote servers are configured to connect to git.

```
ssh root@Server 
git init
git clone gitproject.
```

This doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. I feel the script steps are run asynchronously and thus the clone fails with .git not found.

Comment: `This doesn't work` means what exactly? Any Error messages ? Is the dot `.` after `gitproject` intentional ?

Comment: Maybe simply `ssh root@Server 'git clone Your-URL /tmp/A'` ?

Comment: try to use this way to finish your problem.[reference URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872037/how-to-use-the-gitbash-to-clone-data-with-ssh-windows-10-environment/58872674#58872674)

Answer (score 0):

You said: `"I feel the script steps are run asynchronously"`, 
this indicates you are doing all this in a script and therefore your `git init` and `git clone` are done local. You won't actually need `git init` here.

### Clone the repository remotely on the server

`ssh root@server 'git clone gitproject /tmp/A'`

to issue the command on the server and have it cloned there.