# How to use the GitBash to clone data with ssh (windows 10 environment)

Tags: windows, git, windows-10, gitlab, git-clone

What can I solve this problem?
when I wanted to connect my personal GitLab account, I got an error message like the following picture

```
### shell script     
git clone git@gitlab.com:<username>/test1.git
```

[image]

> GitLab server-side

[image]

> Clone ssh address

[image]

PS: I have checked and found some reference from StackOverflow but unfortunately it isn't okay for me
1.[git clone through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167905/git-clone-through-ssh)
2.[SSH and Git Clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285497/ssh-and-git-clone)
3.[git clone with ssh issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969249/git-clone-with-ssh-issue)

Comment: Did you find your ssh keys (private and public) in your local machine at this location using git-bash `~/.ssh` ?

Comment: @A.Henteti yes! thanks for your reminder me, I found a solution to handle this issue , thanks again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+permission+denied+publickey

Comment: It appears to be due to multiple public keys, one of the other answers in @phd's link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21938804/129686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a great reference but sorry for [Mandarin website](https://kuanyui.github.io/2016/08/01/git-multiple-ssh-key/), however, I can use my way to share how to deal with this issue.

Step 1:

```
ls -al ~/.ssh
```

[image]

Step 2:

```
ssh-keygen
```

(using enter key for default value)
[image]
Step 3: To setup config file

```
vim /c/Users/Willie/.ssh/config
```

> Host gitlab.com
>   HostName gitlab.com
>   User git
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Step 4:

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:<username>/test2.git
```

[image]

Step 5:
When you finished Step 4
1.the test2.git file will be download done
2.you will get the new file(known_hosts) in the ~/.ssh
[image]

PS: I create the id_rsa and id_rsa.ub by myself and I deliver it to the Gitlab server. using both keys to any client-sides(windows and Linux).

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you do have a ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key/~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub public key.

If so, check your private key: if it has 70 chars per line, try and [regenerate with the old PEM format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309):

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

(That will override your current key, but if said current key is not working anyway, that should be OK).
Update the public key on GitLab side, and try again, with a simple:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Using a config file means *not* using the user and using a shorter name:

```
Host gitlab
HostName gitlab.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

means: `ssh -T gitlab` or `git clone gitlab:<username>/test2.git` will work.